# Is Logitech H800 compatible with Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, logitech-headset

I'm interested in buying the *Logitech H800* wireless headset. But customer care told me that it isn't compatible with Linux. They say it's only compatible with Windows & Mac OS X.

But according to [one forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136791), it **is** compatible with Ubuntu.

So, is this the Logitech H800 compatible with Linux? What are the prerequisites to using it on my system? If compatible, will the performance be as good as in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

It works. I couldnt yet have some features working (ie: advanced controls (forward/back)), but except that the input and output are seemingly normal.

I tested this with the (proprietary) USB dongle that is provided with it. Bluetooth to Ubuntu is untested by myself as of yet.

Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10.

Answer (score 3):

Works with the USB dongle both ways: as input and ouput, that is, speakers and mic. If using the bluetooth feature it only works as output (speakers) but the mic isn't detected.

When I plug it as bluetooth it will detect it as `H800` correctly, if I use the dongle it detects it as `H600`.

The button features (play/pause, mute, volume) do work, at least using gnome.

This is on OpenSuSE 13.1 with updated kernel to 3.17.

Short answer: it works.

Comment: I'm using H800 since months. My headset is detected as H800 only by laptop, tablet, Nokia N73. Bluetooth works in my tablet & mobile phone N73 as both speakers & microphone. I talk using headset on tablet & mobile N73. I haven't tested bluetooth connectivity on laptop. So, when you told that bluetooth feature doesn't work for microphone, is it for laptop ???? Because otherwise bluetooth works superbly as microphone on tablets & mobile phones.

Comment: @Ravi Yes, on laptop, as bluetooth (at least for me) only works as output, not on both directions, if I use the dongle however, it does work as output (speakers) and input (mic)

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time trying to get the h800 headset working with Linux Mint XFCE, I was almost about to give up.  Try plugging in the USB receiver into the blue 3.0 port on your computer. For whatever reason they will only work with the 3.0 ports on my computer. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly with Ubuntu 12.04. I tested it with USB and with the nano receiver.

Comment: yes yes i've tested too. works great on ubuntu. tested on ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested Logitech H800 wireless headphones. They works with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Samsung laptop both via bluetooth and via nano receiver.

I think quality is slightly better via nano receiver on my laptop, but this can be my laptop's hardware issue, because it's ~3.5 years old. I haven't tested microphone yet via Skype or Hangouts, but system indicators shows that sound is detected, so I suppose it should work.